# App Crash on GPUImageVideoCamera at glDrawArrays

Tags: ios, gpuimage

As i integrated GPUImage for one of our Application. I found frequently crashes on one Point. 
My Source Code is described Here.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, chrominanceTexture);
glUniform1i(yuvConversionChrominanceTextureUniform, 5);

glUniformMatrix3fv(yuvConversionMatrixUniform, 1, GL_FALSE, _preferredConversion);

glVertexAttribPointer(yuvConversionPositionAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(yuvConversionTextureCoordinateAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0,                [GPUImageFilter textureCoordinatesForRotation:internalRotation]);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

While debugging we found that Crash is occurred at `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)` this line.

Can any one help me about this crash.

//Declaration In Inrterface

GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera;
GPUImageOutput *filter;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GPUImageView *cameraView;

//Implementation
//To Blend image on live video

```
filter = [[GPUImageNormalBlendFilter alloc] init];
[videoCamera addTarget:filter];
[filter addTarget:cameraView];

    GPUImagePicture *overlayImage = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfFrames objectAtIndex:index]] smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
    [overlayImage processImage];
    [overlayImage addTarget:filter];
```

We are applying filter using given sequence.
GPUImageVideoCamera —> GPUImageNormalBlendFilter —> GPUImageView

```
(void)convertYUVToRGBOutput;
{
@autoreleasepool {
@try {
[GPUImageContext setActiveShaderProgram:yuvConversionProgram];

    int rotatedImageBufferWidth = imageBufferWidth, rotatedImageBufferHeight = imageBufferHeight;

    if (GPUImageRotationSwapsWidthAndHeight(internalRotation))
    {
        rotatedImageBufferWidth = imageBufferHeight;
        rotatedImageBufferHeight = imageBufferWidth;
    }

    outputFramebuffer = [[GPUImageContext sharedFramebufferCache] fetchFramebufferForSize:CGSizeMake(rotatedImageBufferWidth, rotatedImageBufferHeight) textureOptions:self.outputTextureOptions onlyTexture:NO];
    [outputFramebuffer activateFramebuffer];

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,
    };

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, luminanceTexture);
    glUniform1i(yuvConversionLuminanceTextureUniform, 4);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, chrominanceTexture);
    glUniform1i(yuvConversionChrominanceTextureUniform, 5);

    glUniformMatrix3fv(yuvConversionMatrixUniform, 1, GL_FALSE, _preferredConversion);

    glVertexAttribPointer(yuvConversionPositionAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(yuvConversionTextureCoordinateAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, [GPUImageFilter textureCoordinatesForRotation:internalRotation]);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);  <—-  Causes Crash Over here

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Exception:%@",exception.description);
}
```

Comment: Is there any error message in the logs?

Comment: As @Larme mentioned, can you provide a bit more informations? A crash in glDrawArrays is usually related to an OpenGL error, like drawing with providing an invalid offset or buffer. Your chunk of code looks like an excerpt of convertYUVToRGBOutput from GPUImageVideoCamera. Is this correct or do you use the same code in another place ? How do you initialize this instance ? do you use specific vertices/attributes/buffers ?

Comment: @lazi74 i updated my question. Please see my code base.